# Pandas: make monthly slice of DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I would like to slice a DataFrame *df* month by month. How import numpy as np

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((200,3)))
df['date'] = pd.date_range('2017-1-1', periods=200, freq='D')
mask = (df['date'] == pd.to_datetime('2017-06')) # ??? all rows for JUNE ???
print(df.loc[mask])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If need compare only by months and year is not important use [`dt.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.month.html):

```
mask = (df['date'].dt.month == pd.to_datetime('2017-06').month)
#same as
#mask = (df['date'].dt.month == 6) 
print(df.loc[mask])
            0         1         2       date
151  0.667722  0.421487  0.338626 2017-06-01
152  0.712709  0.984242  0.419231 2017-06-02
153  0.509679  0.319629  0.651422 2017-06-03
154  0.987976  0.937703  0.278857 2017-06-04
...
```

But if need compare by month period, `years` and `month` are important, use [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html):

```
mask = (df['date'].dt.to_period('M') == pd.to_datetime('2017-06').to_period('M')) 
print(df.loc[mask])
            0         1         2       date
151  0.702137  0.873511  0.458284 2017-06-01
152  0.809441  0.888400  0.350705 2017-06-02
153  0.425821  0.712912  0.339203 2017-06-03
154  0.151374  0.154301  0.923882 2017-06-04
...
```

Solution with [datetimeindex partial string indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#datetimeindex-partial-string-indexing):

```
df = df.set_index('date')
print(df.loc['2017-06'])
                   0         1         2
date                                    
2017-06-01  0.785634  0.496983  0.786512
2017-06-02  0.280444  0.091523  0.468411
2017-06-03  0.429112  0.510265  0.885642
2017-06-04  0.037233  0.034625  0.515339
2017-06-05  0.863211  0.632449  0.396963
2017-06-06  0.550682  0.975060  0.182594
...
```